# Dynamic SQL Where statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to have a single SQL query that will use (if it is set) a parameter to get a specific id of a table otherwise if its NOT set..then to do a where in clause (as the example below)

```
Declare @projectId varchar(255) = '31DEC523-1234-1234-1234-0E6D5CFEC249'

select * from projects where projects.id = @projectId

select * from projects where projects.id in (select top 2 id from projects)
```

How could i join the above into a single query?

I have tried a version of the following which is like 50% of the way there..but i cannot figure out how to do the optional in (SELECT)

```
Declare @projectId varchar(255) = '31DEC523-F19A-4B13-A73C-0E6D5CFEC249'

select * from projects 
WHERE  
projects.id LIKE @projectId+'%'
OR      @projectId IS NULL
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Guessing it is Microsoft SQL Server, because of the use of `+` for string concatenation, and the tendency for many Microsoft users to use [tag:sql] to mean [tag:sql-server].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
select * from projects 
WHERE  
projects.id LIKE @projectId+'%'
OR  (@projectId IS NULL 
     AND projects.id IN (select top 2 id from projects)
```

Like Gordon wrote in his answer an `Order By id` would make alot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add `top (2)` to the query:

```
select top (2) p.*
from projects p
where p.id LIKE @projectId + '%' or @projectId IS NULL;
```

This assumes that the `like` returns one row (or at least never more than 2).

If it could, then `union all` might be simplest:

```
select p.*
from projects p
where p.id like @projectId + '%'
union all
select top (2) p.*
from projects p
where @projectId is null;
```

Note that this returns two *arbitrary* project ids -- just like your query.  If you want two specific ones, then use an `order by`.

These also make the assumption that `id` is unique in `projects` -- which seems like a very reasonable assumption.